# Attempting to Invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get my app to open to a specific webpage. However, when the button is clicked, the app crashes and throws the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.LayoutInflater android.view.Window.getLayoutInflater()' on a null object reference

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_schedule, menu);
    return true;
}
```

The layout that is called is not null and it exists. What is the problem?

Comment: try using `getSupportMenuInflater()` if you are using `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: can you post your logcat please.

Comment: Thanks for the reply inner_class but I found a work-around. The getSupportMenuInflater() did help though.

Comment: Mind sharing that work-around?

Comment: John, I honestly just retyped the method. I'm not sure what the problem was but when i rewrote the method, it worked.